Unable to run chgrp inside a docker container that mounts to an NFS
I have a gitlab server that can be started up with a docker-compose.yml file.
The gitlab server runs on a Macbook Pro computer.
There are 3 volumes inside the docker-compose.yml file.
volumes:
   - './config:/etc/gitlab'
   - './logs:/var/log/gitlab'
   - './data:/var/opt/gitlab'

Today I want to try if the volumes can be changed to an NFS of a Synology NAS.
So I type the following commands to create a mount point.
sudo mkdir /Volumes/my-backup
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw nas.mydomain.com:/volume1/my-backup /Volumes/my-backup

Then I change the volumes section of docker-compose.yml file to this:
volumes:
  - '/Volumes/my-backup/gitlab-mount-volume/config:/etc/gitlab'
  - '/Volumes/my-backup/gitlab-mount-volume/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
  - '/Volumes/my-backup/gitlab-mount-volume/data:/var/opt/gitlab'

/Volumes/my-backup/gitlab-mount-volume/data/ folder contains the files that are created with cp -a ./data/* /Volumes/my-backup/gitlab-mount-volume/data/ command.
-a option can preserve the owner, group, and permissions of all the copied files.
Then I see the following error messages after running docker compose up command
gitlab-service-web-1  | ---- Begin output of chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories ----
gitlab-service-web-1  | STDOUT:
gitlab-service-web-1  | STDERR: chgrp: changing group of '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories': Operation not permitted
gitlab-service-web-1  | ---- End output of chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories ----
gitlab-service-web-1  | Ran chgrp git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories returned 1

Why does chgrp command generates an Operation not permitted error inside the docker container?
I've run cat /etc/export command to check that the mount point contains no_root_squash option.
192.168.123.123(rw,async,no_wdelay,crossmnt,insecure,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)


I think cp -p   does do preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps, not -a ?

Does the group git exist inside the container?

Hi, @JohnGordon groupgit exists inside the container. I can see git in the output of getent group command.
The output is git:x:998:gitlab-backup.
